# What is the replacement for the joint actuator block in the 2nd generation Simscape Multibody?

Tags: matlab, simulink, solidworks, simscape, actuator

I am following a course on designing a TR3 Manipulator in `SolidWorks` , exporting an `XML file` via Solidworks which can be imported via MATLAB into `Simscape Multibody` and then trying to create a control system for it. 
Unfortunately,`Simscape` has changed over the years and the joint actuator block in Simscape is no longer present.

At this point please look at the 2 pictures`(1st one - course , 2nd one - my implementation)`

[image: The Course's Implementation]

[image: My own Implementation]

I have tried to connect the multiplexer directly to the revolute joint.Unfortunately, I get the following error

`Error in port widths or dimensions. Output port 1 of 'TR3RobotExport/Mux' is a one dimensional vector with 3 elements.
Component:Simulink | Category:Model error
Error in port widths or dimensions. Input port 1 of 'TR3RobotExport/Simulink-PS Converter' is a one dimensional vector with 1 elements.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot of the course image is not readable.

As for the revolute joint, the input for the revolute joint torque should be scalar. The revolute joint has only one axis of rotation, so a vector would make no sense.

It may be that the provided example used prescribed motion actuator since these need to be bundled into one signal:

[image]